# JsonConvert unexpected behavior when serialising Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

Hell all! I have a `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<CustomClass,string>>` that i want to serialise.
The result I expect is something like:

```
{
  "key1":{
          {
            "CustomClassProperty1":"val1",
            "CustomClassProperty2":"val2",
            "CustomClassProperty3":"val3"
          }:"Final STR",
          {
            "CustomClassProperty1":"val10",
            "CustomClassProperty2":"val2",
            "CustomClassProperty3":"val35"
          }:"Final STR4",
          {
            "CustomClassProperty1":"val100",
            "CustomClassProperty2":"val25",
            "CustomClassProperty3":"val300"
          }:"Final STR8"
         },
  "key2":{
          {
            "CustomClassProperty1":"val4",
            "CustomClassProperty2":"val5",
            "CustomClassProperty3":"val6"
          }:"Final STR 2"
         },
  "key3":{
          {
            "CustomClassProperty1":"val1",
            "CustomClassProperty2":"val7",
            "CustomClassProperty3":"val5"
          }:"Final STR 3",
          {
            "CustomClassProperty1":"val10",
            "CustomClassProperty2":"val2",
            "CustomClassProperty3":"val35"
          }:"Final STR0",
          {
            "CustomClassProperty1":"val100",
            "CustomClassProperty2":"val25",
            "CustomClassProperty3":"val300"
          }:"Final STR10"
         }
}
```

But instead i'm getting

```
{
  "key1":{
          "MyProjectNamespace.CustomClass":"Final STR",
          "MyProjectNamespace.CustomClass":"Final STR4"
         },
  "key2":{
          "MyProjectNamespace.CustomClass":"Final STR 2"
         },
  "key3":{
          "MyProjectNamespace.CustomClass":"Final STR 3"
         }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to make it right? I dont want the "namespace.classname" but the properties... I`m using Newtonsoft.Json btw... tks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want is valid JSON. http://www.jsonschema.net/ doesn't like it.

Comment: @TimS. i know... i dont really know what is the correct form for this... the ideia is that i want the key serialized full... and not only the namespace.className... i think its quite clear...

Comment: @Leonardo Keys in JSON objects *have to be strings*. That means you can't directly serialize your `Dictionary` as a JSON object. You have to decide how exactly do you want to serialize it and tell that to the serializer.

Comment: @svick hummmm interesting... i didnt know that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output isn't in [JSON format](http://www.json.org/). The left hand side of the `:` is the name of the object property, and must be a string. To get the format you've listed, you'll need to use another serializer that supports your non-JSON format.